# how to re-compile netcat with options?

Tags: shell, unix, netcat

Silly question but I'm not very good at configuring from shell. I want to re-compile my version of netcat with the -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE option enabled. I have the source code downloaded in my computer and I can install it normally by running:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

but how do I enable this option on a Unix system? Thanks. (also it's for a class project. not actually trying to hack...haha)

Comment: Just use socat. It can do all that and more without quirky historical compile options.

Comment: In June 2019, www.ihtb.org no longer leads anywhere useful (unless you find irrelevant ads and malware useful).  Netcat 0.7.1 from 2004 can be obtained from SourceForge's [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) project. (The signature used to sign the RPMs has long since expired.)  The NMAP site also claims to have NCAT (a 21st Century Netcat) built into it — https://nmap.org/ncat/.

Answer (score 1):

```
./configure  --enable-DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE
```

```
./make
```

```
cd src
```

```
./netcat --help
```

Answer (score 0):

The manual says:

> -=* Compiling Netcat *=-
>
> ```
> [ Enable -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE ]
>   While this option makes netcat very powerfull, it is also a huge risk in the wrong hands.. 
>    Damn hackers.
>
> [ Enable -DTELNET ]
>   Without this option netcat will be unable to connect to a telnet server. Telnet servers &
>    there clients auto negotiate there options before the login prompt is displayed. Enabling 
>    this option allows netcat to support this functionality.
>
>   # DFLAGS = -DTEST -DDEBUG
>   DFLAGS = -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE -DTELNET
>   CFLAGS = -O
> ```

So, edit the makefile and adjust the setting of DFLAGS.  It also implies that might be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
./configure -DGAPING_SECURITY_HOLE
make Linux
```